# MySQL Multiple Where Clauses from multiple tables

Tags: conditional-statements, where-clause

I would like to select data from two tables. The 2nd table has multiple entries with a relationship to the 1st.

1st Table - Part

| Part_id | Repair no. | Report no. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | null | 1234 |
| 3 | null | null |
| 4 | 4545 | null |
| 5 | null | null |

2nd Table - Part_History (multiple Histories per Part)

| PartHist_id | Part_id | foo | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2 | null | (d/t) |
| 1234 | 2 | 1234 | (d/t) |
| 2277 | 3 | null | (d/t) |
| 4545 | 4 | null | (d/t) |
| 5444 | 4 | null | (d/t) |

What I would like is to be able to get one of the last Part_History per Part_id, organised by Datetime, BUT if a "Repair no." is NOT NULL or "Report no." is NOT NULL then this should override the Datetime and instead return the PartHist_id with the Repair no. or Report no. value.

`SELECT MAX(Part_History.Datetime) AS Datetime, Part_History.foo, Part_History.Part_id, Part_History.PartHist_id

FROM Part_History

GROUP BY Part_History.Part_id
ORDER BY Part_History.Part_id DESC`

This works fine to get the latest Datetime as a single Part_History row per Part_id, but I am stuck when it comes to adding the Repair no. or Report no. clause.

I have tried to WHERE - CASE the results but never obtained anything that worked.